# Pandas Dataframe: split string column value into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I need split a column in  data frame with a string separated with semicolon in multiple columns, but need preserve the trailing and leading spaces.
Result need to be similar with this example:

```
import re

text = '    ;2022;01;4306809;XX; XXXXXXX;  0  ;internet;ETHERNET;10 ;    '    

print(re.split(';', text))

# output: ['    ', '2022', '01', '4306809', 'XX', ' XXXXXXX', '  0  ', 'internet', 'ETHERNET', '10 ', '    ']
```

I'm looking for same result when using `pandas` to load a CSV file whose lines are the same as in the example above. It don't keep the spaces from the start and end of line (empty cell).

Please ignore why I upload the CSV file without a separator. I have to do several treatments according to the data type and `pandas` usually modifies them. For this reason, I force them as a string as well. It is a generic treatment regardless of the number of columns that come in the files. Don't worry about the header, I save it in the first chunk to use on next chunks.

```
path_file = 'FILE.csv'
chunksize=400    

with pd.read_csv(path_file, sep="#$@", dtype=str, chunksize=chunksize, header=None, engine='python', skip_blank_lines=False
                        , encoding='utf-8-sig', encoding_errors='ignore') as reader:
    for chunk_df in reader:            
        chunk_df = chunk_df[0].str.split(';', expand=True)
        chunk_df.columns = chunk_df.iloc[0]
        chunk_df = chunk_df[1:]            
        display(chunk_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is, you have a column of semicolon-separated values with the headers saved separately and you want to split the column and use the saved headers as column names?

When you `str.split()` the column, you can set the column headers in the same line, like below:

Example DataFrame:

```
text = ['    ;2022;01;4306809;XX; XXXXXXX;  0  ;internet;ETHERNET;10 ;    ']
df = pd.DataFrame(text, columns = ['col'])
```

If you already have a column list, then you can use that. I'm creating a placeholder list of columns here based on the text:

```
df_cols = ['col_' + str(i) for i in range(len(text[0].split(';')))] 
df[df_cols] = df['col'].str.split(';', expand = True)
```

This should give you all the columns, including the empty trailing and leading columns. Note: this is assuming that all the rows will have the same number of columns after splitting.